# materialize css slider showing grey background

Tags: materialize

I am using materialize css for my app, and I using materialize v0.97.0
When I try to use slider it always shows grey background, I have also initialised the slider().

Here's my markup

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12">
    <div class="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="../images/bg3.jpg" alt="slider image"> <!-- random image -->
                <div class="caption center-align">
                    <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
                    <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Plugin initialization
    $('.slider').slider();
})
```

I have also tried various solutions, but nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

Your code is alright assuming that you initialize javascript correctly. Open the page, where your slider is, right click on the grey block and choose view image. If it does not show the image it is supposed to show, then problem is with your image source. Try using source image from the web.
If it shows the image when clicking - view image, the problem is with the initialization of the javascript. Check if your webpage loads correct javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

In JS I wrote following code and it worked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider').slider({full_width: true});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually set the transition times in the javascript to make it work

Put this after the jQuery plugin import

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.slider').slider({
          full_width: false,
          interval: 5000,
          transition: 800,
          });
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: Only "full_width" is neccessary, but this solves my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any error in your JavaScript will prevent to let the slider shows , so check your console when you refresh the page and solve them and you will be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the source of your  tag is pointing to a wrong path.

Just tried your code with a working image path and it worked like a charm.

Please, check if your source path is pointing to the right place. For testing purposes you should try changing your  source to the following:

src="https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"

Comment: I have tried all solutions but nothing worked, I think it is a version issue. So I dropped the idea of using materialze css, now I am using bootstrap.

BTW which version did you use ?

Comment: Using v0.97. However I really don't think it is a version issue. Until the present moment I still couldn't find any major bug using Materializecss, maybe you should give it another try later.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('.slider').slider({full_width: true});
   });
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">

 <div class="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1">
                    <div class="caption center-align">
                        <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2">
                    <div class="caption left-align">
                        <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use this class **transparent**
`<ul class="slides transparent" style="height: 400px;">`